# How to pass QLabel to openCV cv2.imread

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, pyqt

I am trying to import a image using pyqt4 I am displaying it using Qlabel.
Now I want to do some pre-processing on this image , i.e GrayScale, Noise removal, and segmentation.
and display the change when I click on the action button in toolbar.

Here is the code I have made its dosen't work

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from main_window import Ui_MainWindow
import cv2

class module_one(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    "Module One i.e Pre-processing of the Project Handwriting analysis"
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        "Initilization of Class module_one" 
        super(module_one,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.createActions()
    #Open Function  
    def open(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", QtCore.QDir.currentPath(), "Image Files (*.jpg *.jpeg)")
        if filename:
            image = QtGui.QPixmap(filename)
            self.ui.label.setPixmap(image)
            if image.isNull():
                QtGui.QMessageVox.information(self,"Image Viewer","Cannot load %s."%filename)
                return

    #Function that will convert the image into grayscale
    def gray_scale(self):
        image = cv2.imread(self.ui.label) **#Gives Error here**
        gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(gray_scale)

    #Function that will connect all buttons to its function             
    def createActions(self):
        self.ui.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.open)
        self.ui.actionExit.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
        self.ui.actionGray_Scale_Conversion.triggered.connect(self.gray_scale)
```

Which gives the following error

```
image = cv2.imread(self.ui.label)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, QLabel found
```

I know I am passing Qlabel and its expecting string or unicode object.
But, I don't know how to resolve this issue.
Please can anyone tell me what to do or If you have better solution please put forward.

P.S: I am using PyQt4 Designer and OpenCV version 2.4.8

Comment: AFAIK, `cv2.imread()` expects a filename hence the string or Unicode object? So in your case it makes more sense to pass **filename** than a **QLabel**

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out...

Comment: Great, in such case I may post my comment as an answer so you can accept it and let this Q&A close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `cv2.imread()` expects a filename hence it throws the *TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, QLabel found*.

So in your case it makes more sense to just pass **filename** than a **QLabel** `(self.ui.label)`.